# modal form for signup and login rendered twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a component called App which is a Main Component and it has child component like Navbar, Banner( has service type and partner component as child), Destination and many more. The routing has been used inside serviceType component which is a child of Banner component and in Navbar where signup and login form is shown in bootstrap modal.

> The problem is when i click on registrate button the registration form
>   is shown in modal but is also shown just beneath service
>   type(apartment, car, experience).

Here is my code

**app.js**

```
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Nav
            showModal={(e) => this.showModal(e)}
            hideModal={() => this.hideModal()}
          >
           {this.state.show ?
           <ModalForm
            show={this.state.show}
            onHide={this.hideModal()}
           > {this.props.children} </ModalForm> : <span />}
          </Nav>
            <Banner>
              {this.props.children}
            </Banner>
            <Destinos />
            <FindIn />
            <Media />
            <HowItWorks />
            <Footer />
          </div>
          );
  }
```

**routes.js**

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Apartamentos} />
    <Route path="apartamentos" component={Apartamentos} />
    <Route path="coche" component={Coche} />
    <Route path="experiencias" component={Experiencias} />
    <Route path="signup" component={Signup} />
    <Route path="login" component={Login} />
</Route>
```

**Nav.js**

```
const Nav = (props) => (
    <div>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-1">
              <li className="btn-group regLog">
                <button
                  className="btn btn-default"
                  onClick={(e) => props.showModal(e)}
                >
                  <Link to={{ pathname: '/signup' }}>
                    {props.intl.formatMessage({ id: 'nav.registration.text' }) }
                  </Link>
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={props.showModal}
                  className="btn btn-default"
                >
                  <Link to={{ pathname: '/login' }}>
                    {props.intl.formatMessage({ id: 'nav.login.text' }) }
                  </Link>
                </button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
```

**modal-form.js**

```
  render() {
    const { show, onHide, intl } = this.props;
    return (
        <Modal
          show={show}
          onHide={onHide}
          dialogClassName="custom-modal"
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Link to='/login' className="logTitle">
              <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-lg">
                {intl.formatMessage({ id: 'nav.login.text' })}
              </Modal.Title>
            </Link>
            <Link to='/signup' className="logTitle">
              <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-lg">
                {intl.formatMessage({ id: 'nav.registration.text' })}
              </Modal.Title>
            </Link>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            {this.props.children}
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
    );
  }
```

I think the problem is in routes.js. I am confused due to nested component.

Comment: you're rendering `this.props.children` twice in the same component

Comment: are you talking about this.props.children inside Banner?

Comment: You forgot to add a `<ul>` start element in Nav.js.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `{this.props.children}` inside `<Nav/>` and move this

```
{props.show ?
              <ModalForm
                show={this.state.show}
                onHide={this.hideModal()}
              > {this.props.children} </ModalForm> : <span />
            }
```

to app.js file and change to

```
{this.state.show ?
              <ModalForm
                show={this.state.show}
                onHide={this.hideModal()}
              > {this.props.children} </ModalForm> : <span />
            }
```

Comment: I updated with your code  but the form are still shown beneath the service type and now the modal is not appearing either.

Comment: is it the right place to place that code(ModalForm)? I have placed it inside <Nav></Nav> in app.js.

Comment: Could you check state.show value(on clicking of button)?

Answer (score 0):

The way i could solve this problem is

**app.js**

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Nav
            showModal={(e) => this.showModal(e)}
            hideModal={() => this.hideModal()}
            show={this.state.show}
            onHide={() => this.hideModal()}
          >
            {this.props.children}
          </Nav>
            <Banner>
              { location.pathname === '/' || location.pathname === '/apartamentos' ||
              location.pathname === '/coche' || location.pathname === '/experiencias' ?
               this.props.children : ''
             }
            </Banner>
            <Destinos />
            <FindIn />
            <Media />
            <HowItWorks />
            <Footer />
          </div>
          );
  }
```

**nav.js**

```
const Nav = (props) => (
    <div>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-1">
              <li className="btn-group regLog">
                <button
                  className="btn btn-default"
                  onClick={(e) => props.showModal(e)}
                >
                  <Link to={{ pathname: '/signup' }}>
                    {props.intl.formatMessage({ id: 'nav.registration.text' }) }
                  </Link>
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={props.showModal}
                  className="btn btn-default"
                >
                  <Link to={{ pathname: '/login' }}>
                    {props.intl.formatMessage({ id: 'nav.login.text' }) }
                  </Link>
                </button>
                {props.show ?
                  <ModalForm
                    show={props.show}
                    onHide={props.onHide}
                  > {props.children} </ModalForm> : <span />
                }
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
```

I don't think this is the best way. Do anyone have better solution?